# Can you reuse a fragment in multiple activities but with different functionalities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Say I have a fragment that has three buttons and I want to reuse it for at least three activities, but I want those buttons to do different things for each activity. For example, in ActivityA, I want button1 to open Google Maps while in ActivityB, button1 goes to the music player. Is this possible or even the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. Just create an interface for the Fragment, let's say `FragmentCallback`, with your desired callback method, `onButtonClick()` for instance. In the `onAttached()` of your Fragment, cast the Activity to your new interface and store it in a variable `private FragmentCallback callback;`. Each Activity using this Fragment must implement this callback interface. Then call the callbacks `onButtonClick()` method in your Fragments `onButtonClick()` method. That's it - a very common pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

It definetely is. You could just check which `Activity` is hosting your `Fragment` instance:

```
private void button1OnClick(){
 /* could also use instanceof, BUT: if you have something like ActivityC extends ActivityA 
         then instanceof would evaluate to true for both */
   if(getActivity().getClass().equals(ActivityA.class)) {
     // do stuff
   } else if(getActivity().getClass().equals(ActivityB.class)) {
     // do another stuff
   }
}
```

> Is this the right way?

(*attention opinionated answer*)
It depends. If you have a complex and unique layout/functionality, I'd use different `Fragments`. If you have a simple layout with some buttons that just need to act differently in different `Activities` it is a good idea to reuse an existing `Fragment` class.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it this way as well and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you have to add more logic to your fragments and add some interfaces for each activity.
I don't recommend to do that, maybe you could reuse your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

```
if(getActivity() instanceOf ActivityA) {
    //do stuff related to ActivityA
} else if(getActivity() instanceOf ActivityB) {
    //do stuff related to ActivityB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activities have different logic, you can define the button logic in each of them and share the views in this way. You can use a fragment to accomplish this however you can be more direct by sharing a partial layout.

Create a partial layout called three_buttons.xml

three_buttons.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
<BUtton android:text="button 1"/>
<BUtton android:text="button 2"/>
<BUtton android:text="button 3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_a.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView android:text="I am A"/>
<include
            android:id="@+id/three_buttons"
            layout="@layout/three_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_b.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView android:text="I am B"/>
<include
            android:id="@+id/three_buttons"
            layout="@layout/three_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```